# Writing command in R to remove outliers in residual plot

Tags: r, outliers

I want to delete outliers  (defined as more than 2 standard deviations from the mean) in the residual plots ?

what command should I write?

```
DF.mod.2<- lm(X ~ A+ B+ C+ D+ F, data=DF)
```

I got the mean of residuals by this command:

```
mean(resid(DF.mod.2))
```

and standard deviation by this command:

```
sqrt(deviance(DF.mod.2)/df.residual(DF.mod.2))
```

Then how could I exclude the residuals (which have distance more than 2 standard deviations from the mean) from my data frame?

the residual plots:

[image]

Please help me... I am working on these data for one week and I do not know how to remove outliers! I am allowed to remove 200 outliers (not more).

Comment: Please edit your post with some example data. For tips on creating reproducible examples in R, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: if you had >200 points qualifying as outliers, how would you decide which ones to exclude?

Comment: I do not know! do you have any recommendation? I even do not know how many outliers my data frame has!

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of ways you can do this. A simple strategy is to first save your residuals  to the `data.frame` as a new column. Then you can add a second new column to flag if a residual is an outlier or not. You can then use that column to either make a new `data.frame` without outliers or subset your current `data.frame` or whatever else you need. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(20) #sets the random number seed.

# Test data and test linear model
DF<-data.frame(X=rnorm(200), Y=rnorm(200), Z=rnorm(200))
LM<-lm(X~Y+Z, data=DF)

# Store the residuals as a new column in DF
DF$Resid<-resid(LM)

# Find out what 2 standard deviations is and save it to SD2
SD2<-2*sd(resid(LM))
SD2
#[1] 1.934118

# Make DF$Outs 1 if a residual is 2 st. deviations from the mean, 0 otherwise
DF$Outs<-ifelse(abs(DF$Resid)>SD2, 1, 0)

# Plot this, note that DF$Outs is used to set the color of the points.
plot(DF$Resid, col=DF$Outs+1, pch=16,ylim=c(-3,3))
```

[image: Plot with outliers]

```
#Make a new data.frame with no outliers
DF2<-DF[!DF$Outs,]
nrow(DF2)
#[1] 189    Was 200 before, 11 outliers removed

# Plot new data
plot(DF2$Resid, col=DF2$Outs+1,pch=16, ylim=c(-3,3))
```

[image: Plot with outliers removed]

That is the basic idea. You can combine some of these commands - you could just create the outliers column without saving `SD2` for instance, and you don't really need two `data.frames` - you could just exclude the outliers rows when you need to.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can filter using something like :

```
z[abs(z-mean(z))<2*sd(z)])
```

Where z is `resid(DF.mod.2)`

Comment: Thank you very much.  How should I write this in RStudio? First I should write: z<- resid(DF.md.2) then I should write z[abs(z-mean(z))<2*sd(z)]) ? If I want to plot residuals I should use this command: z<- lm(X ~ A+ B+ C+ D+ F, data=DF) and residualPlots(z) ? Am I right?

Comment: I wrote those commands. would you please tell me how to draw the residual plot of filtered data farme?

Comment: with respect, @PotentialScientist, you seem a little out of your depth.  You might need to get some local help or sit down and work through an introduction to R -- Stack Overflow is good for getting over occasional hurdles, but it can't teach you a new programming language ...

Answer (score 0):

```
df = read.csv("SalesData.csv")

LinReg = lm(data = df, Sales ~ OrderCount)

standardized_residuals = scale(LinReg$residuals)
df_outlier = ifelse(abs(standardized_residuals > 2), 1, 0)
df_inliers = df[ !df_outlier,]

LinReg = lm(data = df_inliers, Sales ~ OrderCount)
```